# Django-admin: cant access admin backend "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Not sure what the issue is here, but I am attempting to access my admin backend locally within my django project and I am receiving the following error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  213.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  190.             if not self.has_permission(request):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in has_permission
  143.         return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  184.             self._setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in _setup
  248.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in <lambda>
  16.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in get_user
  8.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in get_user
  98.         user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in __getitem__
  39.         return self._session[key]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_session
  165.                 self._session_cache = self.load()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in load
  23.             self.create()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in create
  35.                 self.save(must_create=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  58.             obj.save(force_insert=must_create, using=using)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1576.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  337.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/
Exception Value: attempt to write a readonly database
```

I am running this project on openshift and my project directory looks similar to this: https://github.com/openshift/django-example

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a python error; it's an issue with your filesystem. You need to check that all read-write permissions are available.

```
$ chown Username /path/to/dbfile.db
```

Answer (score 1):

cd to the folder with that database and do

```
chown www-data:www-data .         (apache2 or httpd for non-debian)
chown www-data:www-data <database>
chmod 700 <database>
chmod 755 .
```

Answer (score 0):

be carefull with changing stuff like @Filip said:

```
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' isn't an available database backend. Try
> using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>     'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql'
```